# Using if...else... in Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arrow-functions

I use the ajax to get information in Vue.js, so my code is:

```
fetch('http://work1999.kcg.gov.tw/open1999/ServiceRequestsQuery.asmx/ServiceRequestsQuery').then(function (response) {
if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
} else {
    commit(roottypes.LOADING, false);
}
```

});

But I use Airbnb JavaScript Style, so I get error:
[https://imgur.com/a/ePeUG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNs2z.jpg)

In order to solve no-else-return and prefer-arrow-callback, so I change my code to:

```
fetch('http://work1999.kcg.gov.tw/open1999/ServiceRequestsQuery.asmx/ServiceRequestsQuery').then((response) => {
if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
}

commit(roottypes.LOADING, false);
```

});

And then, I got a new error:
[https://imgur.com/2qZOqD5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeuCa.jpg)

But only when response is ok, it will return, others will do the function.
How Could I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: `expected a return value` - and yes, you are not returning a value ... how interesting that the error is telling you exactly what the problem is (both else condition in the first code and the non true code in the second code do not return a value) ... try returning something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use arrow function, it should be:

```
fetch('http://work1999.kcg.gov.tw/open1999/ServiceRequestsQuery.asmx/ServiceRequestsQuery')
    .then(response => { return response.ok ? response.json() : commit(roottypes.LOADING, false) });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it showed another error:
http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-confusing-arrow  Arrow function used ambiguously with a conditional expression

Comment: Yes, I change the code as you give,  and get three error. [link](https://imgur.com/MQldTOn)

Comment: So I change again:         `fetch('http://work1999.kcg.gov.tw/open1999/ServiceRequestsQuery.asmx/ServiceRequestsQuery').then((response) => { return response.ok ? response.json() : commit(roottypes.LOADING, false); });`
And get another error. [link](https://imgur.com/bIL6wrQ)

Comment: It will be better if you can change your ESLINT config like below:

{
    "rules": {
        "no-confusing-arrow": ["error", {"allowParens": true}]
    }
} 

Then you can just use parenthesis to prevent the error:

.then(response => (response.ok ? response.json() : commit(roottypes.LOADING, false) ) );

Comment: So is it the better way I change the ESLint config to solve the error?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the better

Comment: Yes, after changed, it's OK.